# iPad Pro 9.7'' power charging

Tags: ipad

I read that the USB-C charger (29W) can "power charge" the large iPad Pro, almost reducing the charging time by a factor 2.

Would the same work with the small iPad Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charger works and can charge the 9.7" iPad Pro. However, it won't do it any faster than the standard 12W charger.

To take advantage of the fast charging, you'll need the 12.9" iPad Pro.